# Telephone Number Not Showing With Letter Class

Tags: letters

I am writing a formal letter using the Letter class. Adding the `\telephone{}` command below `\address{}` in the example found [here](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Letters), the telephone number isn't being added.

```
\documentclass{letter}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\signature{Joe Bloggs}
\address{21 Bridge Street \\ Smallville \\ Dunwich DU3 4WE}
\telephone{123456789}
\begin{document}
    
    \begin{letter}{Director \\ Doe \& Co \\ 35 Anthony Road
            \\ Newport \\ Ipswich IP3 5RT}
        \opening{Dear Sir or Madam:}
        
        I am writing to you on behalf of the Wikipedia project (http://www.wikipedia.org/),
        an endeavour to build a fully-fledged multilingual encyclopaedia in an entirely
        open manner, to ask for permission to use your copyrighted material.
        
        % The \ldots command produces dots in a way that will not upset
        % the typesetting of the document.
        \ldots 
        
        That said, allow me to reiterate that your material will be used to the noble end of
        providing a free collection of knowledge for everyone; naturally enough, only if you
        agree. If that is the case, could you kindly fill in the attached form and post it
        back to me? We shall greatly appreciate it.
        
        Thank you for your time and consideration.
        
        I look forward to your reply.
        
        \closing{Yours Faithfully,}
        
        \ps
        
        P.S. You can find the full text of GFDL license at
        \url{http://www.gnu.org/copyleft/fdl.html}.
        
        \encl{Copyright permission form}
        
    \end{letter}
\end{document}
```

[image: Screenshot]

Why isn't the telephone number displayed? And as an extra question, is it possible to add my email address too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The letter documentation says about the telephone macro:

> Just in case some style puts it on the letter.

To add it you could for example redefine the `\opening`:

```
\documentclass{letter}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\signature{Joe Bloggs}
\address{21 Bridge Street \\ Smallville \\ Dunwich DU3 4WE}
\telephone{123456789}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*\opening[1]{\ifx\@empty\fromaddress
  \thispagestyle{firstpage}%
    {\raggedleft\@date\par}%
  \else  % home address
    \thispagestyle{empty}%
    {\raggedleft\begin{tabular}{l@{}}\ignorespaces
      \fromaddress\\
      Phone~\telephonenum\\*[2\parskip]%
      \@date \end{tabular}\par}%
  \fi
  \vspace{2\parskip}%
  {\raggedright \toname \expandafter\\\toaddress \par}%
  \vspace{2\parskip}%
  #1\par\nobreak}
\makeatother


\begin{document}


    
    \begin{letter}{Director \\ Doe \& Co \\ 35 Anthony Road
            \\ Newport \\ Ipswich IP3 5RT}
        \opening{Dear Sir or Madam:}    
        I am writing to you on behalf of the Wikipedia project (http://www.wikipedia.org/),
        an endeavour to build a fully-fledged multilingual encyclopaedia in an entirely
        open manner, to ask for permission to use your copyrighted material.
        
        % The \ldots command produces dots in a way that will not upset
        % the typesetting of the document.
        \ldots 
        
        That said, allow me to reiterate that your material will be used to the noble end of
        providing a free collection of knowledge for everyone; naturally enough, only if you
        agree. If that is the case, could you kindly fill in the attached form and post it
        back to me? We shall greatly appreciate it.
        
        Thank you for your time and consideration.
        
        I look forward to your reply.
        
        \closing{Yours Faithfully,}
        
        \ps
        
        P.S. You can find the full text of GFDL license at
        \url{http://www.gnu.org/copyleft/fdl.html}.
        
        \encl{Copyright permission form}
        
    \end{letter}
\end{document}
```

[image]